# Cant hide Ionic Tab first

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-tabs

I'm trying to create `Ionic-3 Tab` option, it's working fine, but my issue is I don't want to  display 1st tab in tab menu,but I want to display 1st tab menu in  page details in 1st time page opening ,I'm try to hide this 1st tab , but its not working for me, anyone knows how to do that?I have attached some images on my issue to help you understand it.

[image]

**Tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab0Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Check-In" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Observations" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Activities" tabIcon="book"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Health" tabIcon="medkit"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**Tabs.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import {HealthPage} from '../health/health';
import {MainPage} from '../main/main';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  tab0Root = MainPage;
  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;
  tab4Root = HealthPage;
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Just hide it by css in `tabs.scss` and show it again in which page you want

Comment: @Duannx Sir , can you put it in your answer

Comment: Is [that](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8jmimp) what you want? Tab `Home` show in `HomePage` and `MenuPage` but hide in `ContactPage`

Comment: I want to hide `tab0Root` button and but I want to display `tab0Root` details in app opening

Comment: Did you see my example above?

Comment: @Duannx sir, Yeah, My tab part is working fine, my issue is I mentioned above , look at image

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8jmimp Is that what you want?

Comment: @Duannx omg That is my issue, sir can you put it I Can accept,Thanks lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `Tab` has it own `show` property. So just change it to `false` if you want to hide it.
In `tabs.ts`:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Tabs } from 'ionic-angular';
@ViewChild(Tabs) tabs: Tabs;
ionViewDidEnter(){ 
    this.tabs.getByIndex(0).show = false; 
}
```

Comment: Sir Thanks for the solution and your time

Comment: Sir I had some error why getting this  :(  ` TypeError: _co.tabChange is not a function`

Comment: sorry sir Its my mistake I removed this `(ionChange)="tabChange($event)"` now its work

Answer (score 0):

code side:

```
tab0Root = MainPage;
public isVisibleFirstTab : boolean = false;
```

mark-up:

```
<ion-tab *ngIf="isVisibleFirstTab" [root]="tab0Root"></ion-tab>
```

or
`[rootParams]` could be used for `*ngIf` condition

Comment: Sir Now Im try it, not work, 1st Tab menu is hide but not display in that tab menu details is page opening,

Comment: this is my code `export class TabsPage {
  tab0Root = MainPage;
  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;
  tab4Root = HealthPage;
  public isVisibleFirstTab : boolean = false;

  constructor() {

  }`

Comment: and `<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab *ngIf="isVisibleFirstTab" [root]="tab0Root"></ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs>`